# How can I transfer annotations between PDFs (e.g. using pymupdf)

Tags: pymupdf, pdf-annotations

I have been looking through the pymupdf documentation, and while there is a lot there and I can see how to identify annotations (Annot class), I can't work out how to put an annotation that I have found in one document from that one into another. Has anyone tried this before?

I am trying to merge markups generated in BlueBeam at different times into one document. I don't need to move the annotations around, just to transfer them. If I can assign them to different layers or edit the "name" attribute, that would also be good, but I can probably work out how to do that after they are transferred.

Answer (score 0):

JorjMcKie has answered this over on the [PyMuPDF repository, Issue 1310](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/1310). There is no direct way to merge markups in the way that I would like to do it, but Jorj has demonstrated a way that involves extracting the source data and placing it in the new file (details copied from his response below).

> You can freely access all PDF source identified by an xref via `doc.xref_object(annot.xref, compressed=True/False)`.
> "compressed" False gives you the syntax like above. True will deliver a string without newliners and unnecessary spaces.
> Likewise you can access parts of that source via `doc.xref_get_key(annot.xref, "Subtype")`, which will return `("name", "/Polygon")` in the above case. This latter feature also supports dictionary hierarchies: `doc.xref_get_key(annot.xref, "AP/N")` will give you the `xref` string of the normal appearance dictionary in the form `("xref", "38 0 R")`.

> Vice versa it is possible to use PyMuPDF like an editor for these things:

> `doc.update_object(annot.xref, modified_source)` using some modified postscript version of above
> `doc.xref_set_key(annot.xref, "C", "[1 0 0]")` which in this case will change the stroke color from blue to red.

> All this also works for the PDF trailer: just use -1 instead of a positive `xref`. A unique chance to radically spoil your PDF